# Mozilla localStorage.getItem based on partial knowlege of an unique key

Tags: javascript, local-storage, mozilla

I am looking for quick way to get an item from the Mozilla localStorage based on partial knowledge of an unique key. I have the following structure defined as the key : value

```
UUID1 : "BLABLABLA": UUID2 : Value
```

Where the key part looks like this for example:

```
ca4417f4-f83b-11eb-bf45-ffc420139ccb:BLABLABLA:e1d26c40-f83b-11eb-81c0-fbcc16bf6bdb
```

Value is just a long string.

What would be the fastest way to find a SINGLE key from localStorage based on only one of the two UUIDs i.e.  either UUID1 or UUID2, then obtain the full key string and then use

*localStorage.getItem* to return it's value

maybe using `Object.entries(localStorage)`?

a code example would be really appreciated?

Comment: `Object.entries(localStorage)` should work fine....did you try it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [`Storage` interface](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Storage) has a `length` property telling you how many items are there, and a [`key` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Storage/key) that gives you the key for item index *n*. So you can loop through to find the key with a `for` loop:

```
let key;
for (let n = 0, len = localStorage.length; n < len; ++n) {
    const thisKey = localStorage.key(n);
    if (thisKey.includes("BLABLABLA")) {
        // found it
        key = thisKey;
        break;
    }
}
if (key) {
    const value localStorage.getItem(key);
    // ...
}
```

Note that solutions using `Object.keys`, `Object.entries`, etc. won't work reliably with all storage keys — for instance, the key `"length"` won't work properly even though it's just fine to use `"length'` as a key with `getItem` and `setItem`. That's because the `Storage` interface already defines a property called `length` (the length of the storage list), so you can't access a stored item keyed by `"length'` using `localStorage.length`, you have to `localStorage.getItem("length")`. `Object.keys` and `Object.entries` will leave out those storage entries. *(Other than it appears there's a weird bug in Chrome around the `"key"` key.)* The above works reliably with `length`, `key`, and other similar keys (but really it's `length` and `key` that are the most problematic).

In **your particular case**, though, you know the key isn't `length` or `key` or any of the other things on `Storage.prototype`, so you could create an array of keys via `Object.keys` and use `find` to find the key:

```
// Read the disclaimers above
const key = Object.keys(localStorage).find(key => key.includes("BLABLABLA"));
if (key) {
    const value localStorage.getItem(key);
    // ...
}
```

...or use `Object.entries` to create an array of arrays as [charlietfl shows](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68700618/157247). Just be mindful of the caveat.

Comment: T.J. can you please post an example how this might look?

Comment: in this case i understand that i am looping over the whole map once, and then i use the found key with the method localStorage.getItem to get it's value. thank you.

Comment: @Tito - Almost. You loop through it until you find the key, which may or may not be all the way through (if you're unlucky and it's the last key). But yes, then you use `getItem` to get the value.

Comment: @RoboRobok do you have a better way , regarding the search and find or is the comment related to the key structure UUID1:String:UUID2?

Comment: It's regarding to using the `for` loop.

Comment: @RoboRobok - Because it works reliably, while options relying on the storage keys being properties of the storage object don't. If you know of a **reliable** alternative, the constructive thing to do is to post an answer.

Comment: "really it's length that's the most problematic", `key` is quite common too.

Comment: @Kaiido - Yeah, I'll add that. For me, `key` worked with `Object.keys`, which surprised me. But not with `Object.entries`.

Comment: `key` shouldn't be here from Object.keys either, weird indeed. Seems to be Chrome only.

Comment: @Kaiido - It really shouldn't. :-) `localStorage.key` still returns the function, so there's that at least. And `getOwnPropertyDescriptor` returns `undefined`. Weird.

Answer (score 2):

Expanding on your Object.entries() concept you can do something like:

```
// set a demo key/value
localStorage.setItem('foobar', 100);

const [wantedKey, wantedValue] = Object.entries(localStorage).find(([k,v])=> k.startsWith('foo'))



console.log([wantedKey, wantedValue])
```

[Working jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0ye74L2b/)

Comment: There should be a note about the usual pitfalls of using localStorage as an object directly, namely keys like `length`, `getItem`, `setItem`, `key` etc. won't be retrieved.

Comment: This also won't work on IE11, but that's increasingly irrelevant (though sadly not completely irrelevant yet). Using `Object.keys` would.

Comment: Actually, `Object.keys` would leave out `"length"`, too.